# What is new representatives for well-known values in surreal numbers?!

Tags: surreal-numbers

I know how to obtain surreal numbers in n-day and I know about <= in surreal numbers axiom 2. We will also discover a lot of new representatives for well-known values. For example : $\{-1|1\}=0$ or $\{1/2|2\}=1$ , ...
But I'm confused with some new representatives for example :$\{-2|1\}=0$. Why is not it equal to $-1$ or what is $\{-3|3/4\}=?$ or what is $\{1/4|3\}=?$

Do Anybody know all solution about them(equivalence representatives)?

Note:Please for answer ,don't example to surreal numbers origin representive {0|1}=1/2 or etc. I know about it . I want to know equivalence or new representatives for example $\{-2|1\}=?$ or $\{-4|3/4\}$ or etc...

Comment: What are you taking about ? You do as if everybody knows "surreal-numbers" and what '$n$-day" means in this context, but I fear that almost nobody knows that. You should at least give a thorough web reference !

Comment: @JeanMarie Everyone familiar with/following the tag "surreal-numbers" probably understands what farshad meant by "$n$-day". The [Wikipedia page for the surreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number) addresses what the surreal numbers are and the "day"s of their construction quite thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

$\{a\mid b\}$ always represents the earliest surreal number $x$ (as defined by which day it first appears) such that $a<x<b$ (this also generalises quite naturally to when the left and right sets are not singletons). For instance, if $a$ is negative and $b$ is positive, $\{a\mid b\}$ always represents $0$. As I mentioned in my answer to your [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2327041/list-of-equivalence-surreal-numbers-to-4-day) about surreal numbers, this can get very tedious to check manually for all but the simplest examples.

Comment: Thanks Arthur. What is {1/4|3}=? or etc. please tell me to this example...

Comment: @farshad The earliest number created that lies between $1/4$ and $3$ is $1$, so it represents $1$. You can check with the axiom that $\{0\mid{}\}\leq \{1/4\mid 3\}$ and $\{1/4\mid 3\} \leq \{0\mid {}\}$ if you want to confirm it. In order to do that, you will, of course, have to choose representatives of $1/4$ and $3$, and representatives of the numbers appearing in the left and right sets of those numbers, and so on. I think the proof is doable in less than a page if you choose the shortest (i.e. original) forms for each number.

Comment: Thanks a lot Arthur. Then {3/2|4}=2 because 2 is earliest number created that lies between 3/2 and 3. Do I say true?

Comment: @farshad Exactly.

Comment: Thank you very much Arthur.